# Error when changing to ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf

I am new to WPF and have a beginner question. Whenever I added data to a collection my UI was only getting updated after I restarted the program.  I was originally using ICollection but realized I need to use OvservableCollection to update the collection. When I swtiched the Customers property from ICollection to ObservableCollection I get an error on my UpDate method saying I can't implicitly convert.  Is possible to cast an ObservableCollection. How else could I fix this issue?  Thanks in advance.

> ViewModel.cs

```
 public ViewModel()
    {
        Customers = new ObservableCollection<Customer>();
        UpDate();
    }

    public void UpDate()
    {
        Customers.Clear();
        foreach (var customer in context.Customers.OrderBy(c => c.Name))
        {
            Customers.Add(customer);
        }
    }

    #region Add new customer,project,program,rev methods

    public void AddCustomer(string customerName)
    {
        using (context = new RevisionModelContainer())
        {
            var customer = context.Customers;
            customer.Add(new Customer { Name = customerName });
            context.SaveChanges();
            UpDate();
        }          
    }


 public ObservableCollection<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Project> Projects { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Program> Programs { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Revision> Revisions { get; set; }
    public DateTime Dates { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
```

> Customer.cs

```
  public partial class Customer
{
    public Customer()
    {
        this.Projects = new ObservableCollection<Project>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ObservableCollection<Project> Projects { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

create instance of `Customers` in `ViewModel` constructor

```
public ViewModel()
{
    Customers = new ObservableCollection<Customer>();
    UpDate();
}
```

and populate the list when `UpDate` is called

```
public void UpDate()
{
    Customers.Clear();
    foreach(var customer in context.Customers.OrderBy(c => c.Name)) Customers.Add(customer);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That got rid of the error.  However my collection is still not updating.  I followed this note  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574514.aspx  to change the ICollection occurances with ObservableCollection in the Model.tt and the HashSet in the entity class.  Would you know of anything I could be missing to make sure the ObservableCollection is updating the UI?

Comment: What do you mean by _my collection is still not updating_?

Comment: So if you look at the AddCustomer method in my code I am adding a Customer name to the Customers collection.  This collection is displayed in a combobox on the UI.  When I add another customer name to the Customers collection it is not displayed in the combobox until I restart the program.

Comment: `ObservableCollection` is part of your view model and not EF model. New `Customer` will not appear automatically in your `ObservableCollection`, you need to add it there. So either call `UpData()` or call `Customers.Add(customer)` in `AddCustomer`

Comment: So I actually did call the UpDate() method (see code above) in AddCustomer but still having the problem.

Comment: Regarding the problem with the collection not updating, do you mean that the UI doesn't show customers that were added or do you mean that the collection isn't changing?  Two different problems.  If the customers are added to the collection but the UI is not updating, you've got a problem with your binding.  Look at the Output window for System.Windows.Data errors.